# How to make Ubuntu recognize a FPGA as a hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, ubuntu-drivers

Implemented hard disk behavior on a `FPGA`, I want to connect it via a SATA cable to a system with Ubuntu 16.04 OS. How can I make Ubuntu recognize the logic as a hard disk?

I figured out `udev` is somehow like a device manager, gets the device attributes from kernel and makes a node for the device. But I don't know the mechanism before it; how does the kernel find out the attributes?

I tried to study device drivers, but I've got confused. I was wondering if someone would help me.